# Trouble getting command line arguments in x86 assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write an x86 version of the 'cat' program as a training of syscall calls in assembly.

I'm struggling a lot with command line arguments.
I use the main symbol as an entry point, so I thought I would find the argc parameter in %rdi and the argv parameter in %rsi.
Actually argc is in %rdi as expected, but I keep segfaulting when trying to pass argv[1] to the open syscall.

Not sure of what I'm doing wrong, here is my assembly code:

```
main:
    cmp $2, %rdi            // If argc != 2 return 1
    jne .err1

    lea 8(%rsi), %rdi       // Move argv[1] -> %rdi
    xor %rsi, %rsi          // 0 to %rsi -> O_RDONLY
    xor %rdx, %rdx
    mov $2, %rax            // Open = syscall 2
    syscall

    cmp 0, %rax             // If open returns <0 -> exit status 2
    jl .err2

    mov %rax, %rdi          // Move fd to %rdi
    call cat
    ret

.err1:
    mov $1, %rax
    ret
.err2:
    mov $2, %rax
    ret
```

Comment: How do you assemble and link your code?  If you don't link with the libc, there's nothing that places an argument count into `esi` or a pointer to the arguments into `rdi`.  Instead, you'll have to retrieve the arguments from where the program loader puts them on the stack.  The name of the entry point doesn't matter then.

Comment: I assemble using gcc: gcc -o cat cat.S -no-pie

Comment: Okay, then your code should work.  Note that `lea 8(%rsi), %rdi` retrieves a pointer to the pointer to the second argument.  If you want to obtain a pointer to the string itself (which it looks like it is what you are trying to do), use `mov 8(%rsi), %rdi`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux 64 command line parameters in Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683144/linux-64-command-line-parameters-in-assembly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

First, you use `lea 8(%rsi), %rdi` to retrieve the second argument.  Note that `rsi` points to an array of pointers to command line arguments, so to retrieve the pointer to the second argument, you have to dereference `8(%rsi)` using something like `mov 8(%rsi), %rdi`.

Second, you forgot the dollar sign in front of `0` in `cmp $0, %rax`.  This causes an absolute address mode for address `0` to be selected, effectively dereferencing a null pointer.  To fix this, add the missing dollar sign to select an immediate addressing mode.

When I fix both issues, your code as far as you posted it seems to work just fine.